# Change player volume value in JS/HTML5 Player, but volume stays the same

Tags: javascript, html

I want to lower the default volume on an HTML player.

I can alter the values here:

```
`setAttributes(volumeSlider, { "type": "range", "min": "0", "max": "1",      "step": "any", "value": "1", "orient": "vertical", "id": "volumeSlider" });`
```

http://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/MJPoOr

Changing `value: 1` to `0.1` will make the volume slider lower to 10 per cent, but the playback track volume stays the same.

I've also tried muting and altering values on these two functions, with no effect:

```
function volumizer() {
    if (audioTrack.volume == 0) { setText(muteButton,"volume"); }
    else { setText(muteButton,"volumehigh"); }
}

function muter() {
    if (audioTrack.volume == 0) {
        audioTrack.volume = restoreValue;
        volumeSlider.value = restoreValue;
} else {
    audioTrack.volume = 0;
    restoreValue = volumeSlider.value;
    volumeSlider.value = 0;
    }
}
```

What value do I need to change to lower the track volume programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

What am I missing here... Your example works fine.

When I change the slider, the volume of the track changes both visually, in the console and as audio on this machine.

*If it does not for you it might be a browser issue. I use Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87.*

To see values in the console, press the console button on the lower left and use the console.log function:

```
volumeSlider.addEventListener("input", function(){ 
  console.log(['beforeVolChng', volumeSlider.value, audioTrack.volume]);
  audioTrack.volume = volumeSlider.value; 
  console.log(['afterVolChng', volumeSlider.value, audioTrack.volume]);
}, false);
```

Console.log can take anything: primitive types (int, float, char), objects and arrays etc.

So if your issue is: you want the playback volume on your slider to be applied when you start playing. Let me see.

Here this would be a good solution:

```
audioTrack.addEventListener('playing', 
   function(){ 
      playhead.max = audioTrack.duration; 
      audioTrack.volume = volumeSlider.value; 
   }, false);
```

Comment: The slider works fine, that's not a problem. I want to be able to set the default volume lower using only JS, not the slider. i.e.- I want the slider to start at 50, or 30 % of it's current starting volume. I don't need to console log the values, just hardcode different starting values, as this audio is currently too loud in a mix of sounds I'm creating.

Comment: Well you need some kind of trigger when you want to apply said volume. You can go 2 ways I guess: 

Just hard set the volume you want at the 'playing' event directly or change the position of the slider (which I should do, so the volume the audio plays at actually reflects the slider setting). 

For example:
volumeSlider.value = 0.1;

Comment: I already tried setting volume Slider.value to 0.1, I was surprised when it didn't work.